# rightbarbuttonitem not showing up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibarbuttonitem

NOTE: I can get this to work by switching leftbarbuttonitem to rightbarbutton item in my barbutton and barbutton2 methods. I'm just curious to know why it won't work normally!

For some strange reason, my leftbarbuttonitem is showing, but my rightbarbuttonitem just never pops up! Here's my code

```
    -(void)barButton {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BBut.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage: [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed: @"BBut.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:7.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(showlocations:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame= CGRectMake(3.0, 0.0, image.size.width+1, image.size.height+0);

    UIView *v=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0, 0.0, image.size.width+1, image.size.height) ];

    [v addSubview:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *modal = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:v];
    self.navigation.leftBarButtonItem = modal;


-(void)barButton2 {
    image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Refresh.png"];

    UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage: [image2 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed: @"Refresh.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        // [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(viewDidLoad) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button2.frame= CGRectMake(281.0, 5.0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height);

    UIView *v2=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(281.0, 5.0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height) ];

    [v2 addSubview:button2];
        UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:v2];    self.navigation.rightBarButtonItem = refresh;
    NSLog(@"THE ACTION HAS BEEN RECIEVED!"); }
```

In my ViewDidLoad Method, I have this:

```
[self barButton2];
[self barButton];
```

The action does go through and I do receive my NSLog method. Does anyone know why this is happening? The Left Bar Button always shows up and if I change the the first barbutton to rightbarbuttonitem and change the barbutton2 to leftbarbutton item, and then change the CGRect coords, it works, and that's what I'm using right now to get it to work, but why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the right button because you are drawing it outside the screen.

The `button2` X coordinate is set to 281.0 and its parent view X coordinate is also set at 281.0. As a result your button is in x = 562, meaning it is outside the screen.

Set your `button2` X coordinate to 0 and see if that helps:

```
button2.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 5.0, image2.size.width, image2.size.height);
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I don't know why I understood that it would be in the original views x=281. That was driving me a bit crazy! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a new view with each action and adding a button. So, you never see both buttons. You will need to access the same view in both the actions to make sure you add two button subviews.

Comment: The view's are in different locations though, why would I not be able to see both views at once?